# row_to_json exports "NULL" as "None"

Tags: json, postgresql, azure

I need to export a table row to JSON and store it in an audit table, which is subsequently read and deserialized by a .NET application. There's a function in Postgres that does this:

```
row_to_json(..)
```

My problem is that NULL values are exported as "None" instead of "null":

```
{'id': 'a55fe32b-e113-46a2-b54a-444a15922846', 'description': 'Some description'}
{'id': '195e4926-da42-453a-bb3f-789a823b22c0', 'description': 'Some other description'}
{'id': '31f2a08c-ac18-4579-ad5d-08d7f74557de', 'description': None}
```

Deserialization naturally fails unless I manually create some logic to replace *None* with *null*, but why does it seem like I am the only person having this issue? I have searched for an answer, and seen several examples where *null* is returned as expected from the row_to_json function, while no one else apparently is having this issue.

What am I missing?

**EDIT**: I am also getting boolean values out capitalized (*False* instead of *false* - which is straight out invalid JSON. Something is not quite right with my version of the row_to_json(..)...

**EDIT 2**: I am using Azure Data Studio with the Postgres Extension (microsoft.azuredatastudio-postgresql). This turned out to be the culprit, other clients work as expected and return *null*.

Comment: `with t(x,y) as (values(1, null::text)) select row_to_json(t) from t;` and result: `{"x":1,"y":null}` Could you provide reproducible example?

Comment: If I run that very same query I get this: 

`{'x': 1, 'y': None}`

This is what I mean, it must be something with my Postgres configuration (or version?). But this is also the case in a production database I have access to at work.

Comment: @Abelisto Just ran the same query on Postgres version 9.6.3 with the same result (`{'x': 1, 'y': None}`).

Comment: It is invalid JSON BTW. Key names and strings should be in double quotes.

Comment: Returning None looks like you're call the script from some python method \ code, with something like SQL Alchemy. It looks like you're converting a json obj to a python dict. That's where the None can come from if that's the case.

Comment: I suspect that you are using a client API or programming language that translates JSON `null` to `None`. Please tag and describe what language and API  you are using.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe You were right. I am using Azure Data Studio with a Postgres extension, and as soon as I ran the same query in DataGrip it returned `null` as expected. Thank you, I will update the question with more details and add an answer to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the comment from **@Laurenz Albe** I tried running the query in a different client. The bug is located in the Postgres extension for Azure Data Studio, and other clients (DataGrip) return *null* as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you want to achieve, the json_strip_nulls function will remove any fields that contain nulls. Below is an example:

```
SELECT json_strip_nulls(your_json)
FROM (select row_to_json(row) your_json from (select * from <your_table>) row) p
```

Comment: Thanks, this works but is excessively complicated if there is another way to fix the json export.